# How to known the level of current page in Django-CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

my page.html has this

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags menu_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
  {% placeholder "content" %}
  {% show_menu 2 0 0 100 %}
{% endblock content %}
```

But depend of the level of the current page I have to show different element on the page, something like this

```
{% if node.menu_level == 2 %}
  {% show_menu 2 0 0 100 %}
{% else %}
  #do something different
{% endif %}
```

How to do that? How to know the level of the current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something like this to select a relevant page title based on the ancestry of the page;

```
{% if request.current_page.get_ancestors|length <= 1 %}
    <h1 class="pipe-title pipe-title--inset">
        {{ request.current_page.get_page_title }}
    </h1>
{% else %}
    {% for ance in request.current_page.get_ancestors %}
        {% if ance.depth == 2 %}
            <h1 class="pipe-title pipe-title--inset">{{ ance.get_page_title }}</h1>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

So you could do whatever you wanted based on the page depth in the menu tree.

Comment: Thanks @markwalker_ there is any way to know what is the entire depth of the  menu, and How to know is the current page has child?

Comment: @Stone yeah, there is a `get_descendants()` method as well to go the other way in the tree.

Comment: `request.current_page.node.get_depth` also worked for me.